# React TypeError: this.fetchPosts is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After setup a simple pagination and try to fetch the next page, the log show this error:

> React TypeError: this.fetchPosts is not a function

```
 handleChangePage(page) {
  this.fetchPosts(page);
 }
```

please, someone can enlightenment why can just  pass a function to action triggers?

so what is the purpose of action from the component?

**the pagination component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
 class Pagination extends Component {
 paginationElement(number) {
    return (
      <li key={'page' + number}
          className={number == this.props.page ? 'active' : ''}>
        <a onClick={this.props.handleChangePage.bind(this, number)}>{number}</a>
      </li>
    )
  }
   render() {
    var self = this;
    var page = this.props.page;
    var last_page = this.props.pages;
    var page_links = [];
    var max_elements = 2;
    var pages = [1];

    for (var i = page - max_elements; i <= page + max_elements; i++) {
      if (!pages.includes(i))
        pages.push(i);
    }
    if (!pages.includes(last_page))
      pages.push(last_page);

    pages.forEach(function(i) {
      if (i > 0 && i <= last_page)
        page_links.push(self.paginationElement(i));
    });

    return(
      <div className="text-center">
        <ul className="pagination">
          {page_links}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}




 export default Pagination
```

**the trigger**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Pagination from "../components/pagination";
import axios from 'axios';
class Posts extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
       page: 1,
      pages: 0,
      error: ""
    };
  }



  componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchPosts(this.state.page);
  }


async fetchPosts(page) {
  var self = this;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/posts', {
     headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",

      },
      data: { page: page },

//data: { page: this.state.page },
});

 if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {

         self.setState({ posts: response.data.posts, pages: parseInt(response.data.pages),
         page: parseInt(response.data.page) });

            } else {

                  self.setState({ error: response.data.error});

            }


  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}


    handleChangePage(page) {
    this.fetchPosts(page);
  }



  render() {
    var posts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
      return (
        <div key={post.id}>
          <h1>{post.id}</h1>
          <h1>{post.title}</h1>
          <p>{post.body}</p>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>


      {posts}

 <Pagination page={this.state.page}
                        pages={this.state.pages}
                        handleChangePage={this.handleChangePage} />
                        </div>

      );
  }
}

export default Posts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the trigger

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  ...
  this.handleChangePage = this.handleChangePage.bind(this)
}
```

Or you change function handleChangePage as below:

```
handleChangePage = (page) => {
  ...
  }
```

Recommend: 
You should use bind(this) for function in component. You can declare in contructor.
Or use arrow function